# How do I convert a password to Base64 for Ldap, using Java?

Tags: java, ldap

I am using ldap, working on java,there the password value is a base64 format, how to convert my normal text password sarath_dev to Base64 for Ldap?

Comment: can you show some code of what you've tried so far?

Comment: what do you mean by code? i just want to enter base64 format password in ldap browser....thats all!

Comment: you wanna encode your password in base64??

Comment: but online emcoders are not proper......

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a question about programming or about tools that are used primarily for programming.

Comment: Why convert to base64 for LDAP? LDAP does not require the password be in base64 format.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are not familiar with `base64 encoding` algorithm here is basic introduction. Base64 encodes (changes content of original String) String using an algorithm which uses 64 printable characters to replace each character in original string in an algorithmic sequence so that it can be decoded later. Base64 encoding prevents misuse of data by encoding it into ASCII format. Though there are more advanced encryption algorithm available like `RSA-SHA` and `MD5` and you should use those in production but `base64` is real simple and easy to use for simple encoding needs.

**Encoding & Decoding String into Base64 In Java**

Here is a quick example of encoding and decoding of String in `base64 encoding` algorithm. we will first encode String by converting it into byte array and than passing down to `Base64.encodeBase64(byte[])` which encodes byte array
as per `base64 encoding` algorithm and returns and encoded byte array, which can be converted into String. in Later half we will decode the String by calling `Base64.decodeBase64(byte[])` method.

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
public class Base64EncodingExample{

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        String orig = "original String before base64 encoding in Java";

        //encoding  byte array into base 64
        byte[] encoded = Base64.encodeBase64(orig.getBytes());     

        System.out.println("Original String: " + orig );
        System.out.println("Base64 Encoded String : " + new String(encoded));

        //decoding byte array into base64
        byte[] decoded = Base64.decodeBase64(encoded);      
        System.out.println("Base 64 Decoded  String : " + new String(decoded));

    }
}


Output:
Original String: original String before base64 encoding in Java
Base64 Encoded String : b3JpZ2luYWwgU3RyaW5nIGJlZm9yZSBiYXNlNjQgZW5jb2RpbmcgaW4gSmF2YQ==
Base 64 Decoded  String : original String before base64 encoding in Java
```